# A mysql query from multiple tables without anything in common

Tags: php, mysql

EDIT: Sorry guys, I didn't knew that you can do three SELECT queries on the same page just like that, I thought that the limit was 1 query/page and not 1 type of query/page. I've solved my problem by dividing it into multiple queries, but the question will still remain (just out of curiosity): is it possible to query multiple tables without a WHEN clause that connects the tables **and** without getting a cartesian product?

Thanks for the replies, your many "divide it into multiple queries" replies made me say "What if...is that easy?" :). The original question below:

---

I'm pretty new to mqsql and I ran into the obnoxious cartesian product. I'm trying to query three tables that don't have a column in common (actually there is a connection between the second and the third table, but ignore it). 
I've got the tables t1(c1,c2,c3), t2(c4,c5), t3(c6,c7) and I would like to do something like:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM t1, t2, t3";
$request=  mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$i=0; while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($request))
{
    $array1[$i]=$row['c1'];
    $array2[$i]=$row['c2'];
    $array3[$i]=$row['c3'];
    $array4[$i]=$row['c4'];
    $array5[$i]=$row['c5'];
    $value6=$row['c6'][1];
    $value7=$row['c7'][1];
    $i++;
}
```

All I want are the arrays 1-7 ON THE SAME php PAGE (without adding framesets/frames ecc.)?
I've also tried breaking it in multiple queries after this guy's example http://www.dev-explorer.com/articles/multiple-mysql-queries but it didn't work.

EDIT:
example data

TABLE1:

```
----------------------------
fruit_id | f_name | f_color
----------------------------
1        | apple  | red
2        | banana | yellow
```

TABLE2:

```
----------------------------
player_id | player_name
----------------------------
1         | John
2         | Scott
3         | Mike
4         | George
```

TABLE3:

```
----------------------------
other_id | other_name
----------------------------
1        | Alex
```

I want to be able to get in the same page the arrays
$fruit_id with the values ['1','2'], $f_name ['apple','banana'], $f_color ['red','green'], $player_id['1','2','3','4'] ecc..

It does not have to be mysql, as long as I get those arrays.

Comment: Why are you using `mysql_query`?

Comment: can you post some sample data and expected result?

Comment: if they don't have anything in common, why are you trying to get them all via a single query join? at worst you should be using a `UNION` query, at best run 3 separate queries.

Comment: what do you mean? what should I use?

Comment: `mysql_` functions are deprecated http://www.webmaster-source.com/2011/07/25/php-to-deprecate-mysql-extension-in-favor-of-mysqli-and-pdo/

Comment: Sample data and desired results -- that can help us help you construct your query.

Comment: I'm also open to suggestions in mysqli, anything that will make me obtain those arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. What you are doing in your example is performing the **[cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)** of three tables. That means that **every combination** of the tuples contained in the three tables will be displayed.

   This is likely not what you are looking for, so you should have a look at **joins**, to limit the number of rows.

   MySql supports also [Set operations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) like **Union** if you want to venture in some more complicated and nested queries. However i would advice just sticking with **[joins](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/)**
2. If the data is not actually connected in any way, try issuing multiple queries (without trying to fit everything into one single SQL statement), and output the data manually in whichever form  you want to display them.

Whithout more information about what you're doing, I cannot give you any other advice

Comment: I've added an example, which falls under your 2nd point: not connected in any way. From my (very little) knowledge I'm not able to do multiple queries in the same page, that's why I was trying to jam it all in the same query. I would appreciate a way to do it (I'm google-ing for the multiple queries for some time, with the page that I quoted in the post as the only thing that could apply to my situation).

Answer (score 0):

Just run 3 separate queries, and put the results into different array variables. You are making this WAY too difficult; stop and think about your problem for a few moments without looking at code

You should also look at using PDO rather than the deprecated my_sql_* functions you are using. This will get you started:

http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers